# Math error with beamer but not article - multiple 'missing { inserted'

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath

When I use an align* environment containing some matrices, compilation gives errors when using the beamer class. When I change to article class, compilation is fine. I can't understand what is wrong, or what I need to do to handle this with beamer...

Beamer code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}    
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}    

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\underbrace{\mathrm{d}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \eta_1 \\ 
 \eta_2 \\ 
 \eta_3 \\ 
 \eta_4 \\ 
 \eta_5 
 \end{bmatrix}
\big{(}t\big{)}}_{\mathrm{d} \vect{\eta} (t)}   =  \left(
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 \text{drlatency}  &  \text{drlatencydisturbance}  &  \text{drlatencyquality}  &  \text{drlatencymood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drdisturbancelatency}  &  \text{drdisturbance}  &  \text{drdisturbancequality}  &  \text{drdisturbancemood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drqualitylatency}  &  \text{drqualitydisturbance}  &  \text{drquality}  &  \text{drqualitymood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drmoodlatency}  &  \text{drmooddisturbance}  &  \text{drmoodquality}  &  \text{drmood}  &  \text{drmoodsleep} \\ 
 0  &  0  &  0  &  \text{drsleepmood}  &  \text{drsleep} 
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\underbrace{\vect{A}}_\textrm{DRIFT}} \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 \eta_1 \\ 
 \eta_2 \\ 
 \eta_3 \\ 
 \eta_4 \\ 
 \eta_5 
 \end{bmatrix}
\big{(} t \big{)}
}_{\vect{\eta} (t)} + \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\underbrace{\vect{b}}_\textrm{CINT}}  \right) dt 
\end{align*}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Article code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath} %for multiple line equations    
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}    

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\underbrace{\mathrm{d}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \eta_1 \\ 
 \eta_2 \\ 
 \eta_3 \\ 
 \eta_4 \\ 
 \eta_5 
 \end{bmatrix}
\big{(}t\big{)}}_{\mathrm{d} \vect{\eta} (t)}   =  \left(
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 \text{drlatency}  &  \text{drlatencydisturbance}  &  \text{drlatencyquality}  &  \text{drlatencymood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drdisturbancelatency}  &  \text{drdisturbance}  &  \text{drdisturbancequality}  &  \text{drdisturbancemood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drqualitylatency}  &  \text{drqualitydisturbance}  &  \text{drquality}  &  \text{drqualitymood}  &  0 \\ 
 \text{drmoodlatency}  &  \text{drmooddisturbance}  &  \text{drmoodquality}  &  \text{drmood}  &  \text{drmoodsleep} \\ 
 0  &  0  &  0  &  \text{drsleepmood}  &  \text{drsleep} 
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\underbrace{\vect{A}}_\textrm{DRIFT}} \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 \eta_1 \\ 
 \eta_2 \\ 
 \eta_3 \\ 
 \eta_4 \\ 
 \eta_5 
 \end{bmatrix}
\big{(} t \big{)}
}_{\vect{\eta} (t)} + \underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0 
 \end{bmatrix}
}_{\underbrace{\vect{b}}_\textrm{CINT}}  \right) dt 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that

```
_\textrm{CINT}
```

works by default is an unfortunate side effect of the parsing rules for primitive subscripts which do not match those of normal macro arguments.

if you use the documented syntax

```
_{\textrm{CINT}}
```

then it works in beamer (there are two instances of this in the example)